# How to return value from database

Tags: python, json, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to return the client value from the database in the form of JSON. In the current version of my application comes the answer for the clearly indicated id. How to make so that the client could choose any other value from the database?

my code:

```
@app.route('/json', methods=['POST'])
def status():
    select = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    data = {'id': select.id,
            'name': select.name,
            'balance / hold': [select.balance, select.hold],
            'account status': select.status}
    return jsonify(data)
```

How to request data on other id?:

```
select = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
```

responce:

```
{
    "account status": true,
    "balance / hold": [
        1700,
        300
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Piter Jackson"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
from flask import request
...

@app.route('/json', methods=['POST'])
def status():
    if request.form.get('id'):
        select = User.query.filter_by(id=request.form.get('id')).first()
        data = {'id': select.id,
            'name': select.name,
            'balance / hold': [select.balance, select.hold],
            'account status': select.status}
        return jsonify(data)
    else:
        return jsonify({})
```